# How do you get animations in roblox not to overlap

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

So I am working on a game at the moment and I made an animation that I would like the player to use while walking, I'm having an issue where when the animation plays my character stops moving it's legs and arms. Here is the code that I am using to run the animation, I did not include any variables in it.

```
AnimTrack = plr.Character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Anim)
AnimTrack:Play()
```

Comment: Like @Piglet said, you can't obviously can't achieve this if your animation affects the same body part. If you want to run your animation on top of a core animation (like walking), you can change the animation priority of your own. Read [here](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/enum/AnimationPriority) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't if both animations use the same body parts (even if they do not move them).

The only way to combine animations is to use animations that don't use the same bodyparts (have those disabled which are used by the other animation).

Ideally create your own animations to avoid any unwanted effects.